# How to set variables inside a foreach loop for outside access in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

If I have an array

```
$places = array('year' => '2012', 'place' => 'school');
```

Is there any way of doing this in PHP

```
foreach ($places as $key => $value) 
{
    $key = $value
}
```

But so that variables are being set based on the name of the key.

Eg, variables would be available like so

```
echo $year;
2012
echo $place;
school
```

Comment: You're making things complicated as you can call it directly via key. example `echo $places['year']` or `$year = $places['year']`

Comment: So this kind of practice is generally discouraged? The reason I thought I'd try to do this is because I have a rather long function, and I'd rather just refer to variables with a shorter name instead of having to type the array key followed by the value all the time.

Comment: Unless if your array is multidimensional array , Keep it simple as possible like i said you can just use `$year = $places['year']` or the answer below which is `extract()`

Comment: I would call `extract` "generally discouraged", myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use extract

```
extract($places)

echo $year;

echo $place;
```

Or, you could use variable-variables:

```
foreach ($places as $key => $value) 
{
  $$key = $value //note the $$
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just do like this ?

```
<?php
$places = array('year' => '2012', 'place' => 'school');
echo $places['year'];// prints 2012 This is also synonymous to a variable
```

AFAIK, you are just complicating your example.